# How to validate data against a GraqhQL type

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

Having a GraphQL schema and some JSON object, is there a way to check if the object is a valid type in the schema. The only thing that I've found so far is `isValidJSValue` which only expects `GraphQLInputType`.